# Invalid chacter in name fortran 90

Tags: fortran, character, fortran90

This is probably something really simple but I'm getting the error when compiling my little Fortran program. (The file is .f90) Is this something to do with fixed versus free line length? That seems to be all I could glean from a google search.

Here's the program:

```
program array
    integer :: k, n, i, j, h, f, AllocateStatus
    real*8, dimension(:, :, :), allocatable :: a
    character, parameter :: "fname"

k = 5
n = 5
h = 1
    allocate(a(n,k,h), stat = AllocateStatus)
    if (AllocateStatus /= 0) stop "*** Not enough memory ***"

    a(1,:,:) = 5
a(2,:,:) = 6

call writeArray(7,a,"testOutput")

deallocate(a)

end program array

subroutine writeArray(f,array,fname)
implicit none
integer :: f, i, j, k, n
character, parameter :: "fname"
real*8, dimension(:, :, :), allocatable :: array
        open(unit = f, file="fname")
    do, i=1,n
        do, j=1,k
                write(7,"(F5.2)") array(i,j,:)  
        if (j==k) write(7,"(A1)") "X"
        enddo
    enddo
    !write(7,"(I5)") size(a)

    close(f)
end subroutine writeArray
```

And the errors:

```
test.f90:4.29:

character, parameter :: "fname"
                         1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
test.f90:24.26:

character, parameter :: "fname"
                      1
Error: Invalid character in name at (1)
test.f90:21.35:

subroutine writeArray(f,array,fname)
                               1
Error: Symbol 'fname' at (1) has no IMPLICIT type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree with @kyle. So in heeding those suggestions I would also declare the intent of the variables to the subroutine `writeArray`. Thus the program would be along the lines of:

```
program array
    integer :: k, n, h, AllocateStatus
    double precision, dimension(:, :, :), allocatable :: a
    character(len=1024) :: fname

    fname = "testOutput"
    k = 5
    n = 5
    h = 1
    allocate(a(n,k,h), stat = AllocateStatus)
    if (AllocateStatus /= 0) stop "*** Not enough memory ***"

    a(1,:,:) = 5
    a(2,:,:) = 6

    call writeArray(7,a,fname)

    deallocate(a)

contains

subroutine writeArray(f,array,fname)
    implicit none
    integer,                    intent(in) :: f
    integer                                :: i, j, k
    character(len=*),           intent(in) :: fname
    double precision, dimension(:, :, :), intent(in) :: array

    open(unit = f, file=fname)
    i = size(array, 1)
    k = size(array, 2)
    do, i=1,n
        do, j=1,k
                write(7,"(F5.2)") array(i,j,:)..
        if (j==k) write(7,"(A1)") "X"
        enddo
    enddo
    !write(7,"(I5)") size(a)

    close(f)
end subroutine writeArray

end program array
```

Also I don't like using `real*8`, I tend to either declare it as either `real(kind=8)` or `double precision`.

Lastly, depending on the compiler you use (and hence it's flags), Try to always be as pedantic and chatty as possible. For gfortran I typically use the options `-Wall -pedantic` when compiling.

Comment: Thanks, I've got it now! You've been very helpful!

Comment: And thanks for including the "size" function for the arrays. I definitely wanted to make it more general and was trying to find the syntax for that. :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use quotation marks to denote an initialization. In your subroutine, you should have

```
CHARACTER(LEN=*) :: fname
```

in place of what you have there. You probably do not need the `PARAMETER` statement with the character declaration. The initialization of `fname` does not appear to be needed in the main program.

Another pair of things I noted in your code: (1) you don't need to declare `array` and `ALLOCATABLE` and (2) you ought to start file `UNIT`s at values >= 10 because the single-digit numbers are occasionally associated with (reserved for?) standard out.

---

Another suggestion is that you should either put your `writeArray` subroutine in its own `MODULE` and `USE` it, or write the program as

```
PROGRAM Main
...
CONTAINS
  SUBROUTINE writeArray
  ...
  END SUBROUTINE
END PROGRAM
```

With either method, you will catch inconsistencies in the arguments. Not only that, you will also be able to use the variables `n` and `k` without issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response, you've been very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

Additional comments:

You definitely don't want `parameter` in the declaration of `fname` -- that designates that the "variable" is constant, which is inconsistent with a dummy argument.

You could declare the arguments as:

```
integer, intent (in) :: f
character (len=*), intent (in) :: fname
real*8, dimension(:, :, :), intent (in) :: array
```

The reason that you don't need to declare `array` as allocatable in the subroutine is that you don't change its allocation in the subroutine.  You can obtain the values of `n` and `k` with the `size` intrinsic and so don't need to pass them as arguments.